# yeoman: automatically install npm modules

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I've created a yeoman generator.

Once I've created a project scaffold using my generator, I run the command "npm install grunt-contrib-watch grunt-contrib-connect"

I've been following the doc here: http://yeoman.io/generators.html

It seems to indicate that npm dependencies can be installed automatically. But I can't quiet figure out how to make this happen.

So, how do I define npm depencies in my generator, so that the node modules get installed automatically when the scaffold gets created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate a `package.json` as part of your scaffolding just as any other file. It can even contain template markup, as in [generator-webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/blob/8d36147352155ec62243d4bc6ef2b3e198711149/app/templates/_package.json).

If you scaffold out a `package.json` in the root directory of your generated project, you can run `installDependencies()` of the generator object at the end:

```
this.on('end', function () {
  this.installDependencies();
});
```

This will take care of installing bower and npm dependencies that the project declares.